# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una función que me diga si lo introducido en mi input es un entero y de no ser así, me pida que lo introduzca de nuevo?

Tags: python

Disculpen estoy aprendiendo a utilizar Python y estoy tratando de hacer una función que me diga si lo que introduzco en mi input es un número, en caso de ser una cadena, lo vuelva a pedir hasta que se introduzca un número, pero no se que me falla. Ayuda por favor!

```
def lee_entero(number):
    lista1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]
    if number in lista1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

number = input("Ingrese un número entero: ")
for i in number:
    if lee_entero(i) == False:
        print("Error: No es un número entero.")
        number = input("Ingrese un número entero: ")
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! aclara que hace el programa y que deberia hacer...

Comment: Un número que introduzca el usuario, lo pido en la línea 8.

Comment: Era como para ir haciendo una validación término por término de lo introducido por el usuario (así de esta manera cuando detectara un término que no sea un número, me regresase un False), aunque quizás no es la manera más óptima, pero es lo único que se me ocurría.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrias hacerlo de varias maneras:

***1. Usando una excepción***

```
def main():
    ''' Función principal
    '''
    # El ciclo siempre se ejecuta, y termina hasta encontrar "break"
    while True:
        # Pide el dato al usuario
        dato = input('Ingresa un numero entero: ')

    # La excepción se ejecuta, porque intentas convertir un caracter en numero
    try:
        numero = int(dato)    # Si dato es un numero no pasa nada, convierte el dato en numero
                              # Si dato es un caracter, no se puede convertir en numero y se ejecuta la exepción

        print("Enhorabuena, ingresaste un numero entero!")          
        break                 # Sale del ciclo
    except ValueError:
        print("\n   [✗] Dato invalido: '{}' no es un numero entero.".format(dato))
        print("\n\nPor favor...")
        
print("Aqui estas fuera del ciclo")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ''' Verifica si es el programa principal o ha sido heredado.
    '''
    main()
else:
    print("Función main() no existe")
```

***2. Usando una excepción en una función***

Igual que el primer ejemplo, solo que la excepción la llamas desde una función

```
def verificar_entero(dato):
    # La excepción se ejecuta, porque intentas convertir un caracter en numero
    try:
        numero = int(dato)      # Si dato es un numero no pasa nada, convierte el dato en numero
                                # Si dato es un caracter, no se puede convertir en numero y se ejecuta la exepción

        print("\n\nEnhorabuena, ingresaste un numero entero!")
        return 1                # Retorna 1, si es un entero
    except ValueError:
        print("\n   [✗] Dato invalido: '{}' no es un numero entero.".format(dato))
        print("\n\nPor favor...")
        return 0                # Retorna 0, si NO ES UN ENTERO

def main():
    ''' Función principal
    '''
    # El ciclo siempre se ejecuta, y termina hasta encontrar "break"
    while True:
        # Pide el dato al usuario
        dato = input('Ingresa un numero entero: ')

        if verificar_entero(dato) == 1:     # Si la funcion devuelve un 1 es un entero
            break                           # y sale del programa
                                            # De lo contrario al no encontrar el break
                                            # se vuele a ejecutar el ciclo

    print("Aqui estas fuera del ciclo")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ''' Verifica si es el programa principal o ha sido heredado.
    '''
    main()
else:
    print("Función main() no existe")
```

***3. La manera más estoica posible***

```
while True:
    try:
        # Pide el dato al usuario
        dato = int(input(" Ingresa un numero entero: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("\n   El dato ingresado no es un entero!")
        print("\n\n Por favor...")
        continue
    else:
        break

print("\n\n Enhorabuena ingresaste un entro.")  # Aqui ya estas fuera del while, break ha sido encontrado
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la función [isnumeric()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric) para verificar si el texto introducido corresponde a números, [removeprefix()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removeprefix) elimina el caracter especificado al principio de la cadena.

```
def leer_entero():
    while True:
        number = input("Ingrese un número entero: ")
        if num.removeprefix('-').isnumeric() or num.removeprefix('+').isnumeric():
            return int(number)
        print("Error: No es un número entero.")
        
entero = leer_entero()
```

Comment: Hay un pequeño detalle: `.isnumeric()` te dice si la cadena está compuesta exclusivamente de dígitos, fallando si detecta signo (`+`/`-`) o con el separador de dígitos `'_'`. Por ejemplo, estos númeors enteros fallan tu comprobación: `1_234_567_890`, `-1`

Comment: Corregido para números con signos +/-

Answer (score 0):

lo puedes hacer de una forma fácil con la clausula `try/except` de esta forma.

```
number = input("ingrese un numero: ")

try:
  number = int(number)#convertimos a entero
  print(n)
except:
  #en caso no se pueda, por diversas razones, nos imprime esto
  print("no es un numero entero, por favor digite un numero entero")
```

Lo que hace el `try/except` es tratar de ejecutar el código dentro del `try`, en caso ocurriese un error, se ejecuta el `execpt`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def askNumber():
  try:
    numero = int(input("Ingresa un numero: "))  
  except:
    print("Error: No es un número entero")


while True:
    askNumber()
```

puedes crear una funcion con un try de modo que atrape la excepcion e imprima el error
Saludos.